# Apache zeppelin error

Tags: apache, apache-zeppelin

I have started apache zeppelin and running successfully in the configured port.
While I am executing simple spark commands like

```
sc.version
println(zeppelin)
```

I can just see "ERROR" string near run button without any error output on my console.

My error log :

> ERROR [2016-10-21 22:38:05,837] ({pool-2-thread-6} Job.java[run]:189) - Job failed
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Found both spark.driver.extraClassPath and SPARK_CLASSPATH. Use only the former.
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$validateSettings$7$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(SparkConf.scala:492)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$validateSettings$7$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(SparkConf.scala:490)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$validateSettings$7.apply(SparkConf.scala:490)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$validateSettings$7.apply(SparkConf.scala:478)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.validateSettings(SparkConf.scala:478)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:398)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_1(SparkInterpreter.java:440)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:354)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:137)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:743)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
>       at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Also I have mentioned the spark and java path in `_zeppelin-env.sh_ file`.

Answer (score 0):

*I know, this is quite a late answer, but for any one who faces similar issue.*

Even I had similar issue, I had added some external dependency {**com.twitter:algebird-core_2.11:0.11.0**} in interpreter Mode for Spark. If any dependency added for any component, there might be a case that dependency is not compatible with Zeppelin Version or does not exist on remote. Once I removed that dependency, I started seeing other errors on Zeppelin console.

Just to make sure, "**zeppelin.spark.printREPLOutput**" is set to **true**, generally by default it is true only, but just to make sure!!